# CSS animation: Difference between left:100% and translate(100%)

Tags: css

I have read about how using translate has better performance, but it seems they behave slightly differently: using `left:100%` moves the animated object all the way to the end of the screen, whereas `translate(100%)` only moves the animated object as far as its length. That is, it moves 100% of the screen versus 100% of the object.

Can explain why this is, and what can be done to reproduce the same behavior when using `translate`?

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/32VJV/1/

```
.slide_1 {
    top: 0px;
    left:0%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.slide_1 {
    -webkit-animation: slide 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.slide_2 {
    top: 25px;
    left:0%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.slide_2 {
    -webkit-animation: slide2 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide2 {
    0% {
        left 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left:100%;
    }
    100% {
        left:0%;
    }
}

<div style="font-size:18px;">
    <div class=""> <span class="slide_1" id="dimensions">ABC</span>  <span class="slide_2" id="dimensions">ABC</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but don't use only `webkit`. Use also the conventional way (`animation` etc.).

Comment: Also instead of writing a line for `0%, 50%, 100%` keyframes, you can just keep the one for `50%` and get the same result

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the two is that animating a property like left will keep the element in the flow of the document whereas `translate` does not.

For more information on why you might use one or the other, Paul Irish has an excellent write up (with links to more information): [Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

There's also a lot of great information on browser performance at [jankfree.org](http://jankfree.org/)

Solution for the translate animation: make the element as wide as the window:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/32VJV/3/)

```
slide_1 {
    top: 0px;
    left:0%;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

An interesting exercise: Open your devtools and what what happens when you activate one animation at a time.

In Chrome:

- The translate animation has basically nothing going on except a periodic GC
- The Left animation you will see repeatedly:

  - Recalculate Style
  - Layout
  - Pain Setup
  - Paint
  - Composite Layers

In this case, the overhead it pretty small, but that can change quickly depending on what is being moved around the screen.

Comment: I was going to suggest just setting the width to 100%.  I like the right: 0; better personally. but they both achieve essentially the same thing.  Any reason why one would not want to use width and use right: 0; instead?  Just curious if there's a difference?

Comment: Animate `left` creates lot of reflows in the html, while in translate the element will stay in the same place on the flow, but only the 'visual' part will move.

Comment: @Michael - For a translate, using right: 0 is fine as the whole element is shifted.  Not sure if there would be a case where it wouldn't be ok for translate.

Comment: I just updated http://jsfiddle.net/32VJV/4/ with the right:0
2 things:
 1) the acceleration is not exactly the same
 2) if you drag the 'result' window and change it size, the 'translate' version doesn't updates.

Comment: I believe 1 is likely due to a slight lag in setting up the `left` animation (see above re: recalc style, etc).  Guessing here but 2 is likely that the animation is setup once - I don't know if it would be considered a *bug* or a *feature* of the browser.  You might be able to reset it by removing a class that specifies the animation then re-adding it but it would likely jump as it restarted.  the Left animation has problems as well when resizing.  You can see the animated text stuttering as the window is resized (at least on Chrome) while the translate version stays smooth.